# Is the character of "the Swede" a "method actor" in Hell On Wheels?

Tags: hell-on-wheels, method-acting

According to the real history of the intercontinental railroad, Hell on Wheels takes place in the years just after the American Civil War.  (The [golden spike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_spike) was hammered in in 1869.)

Now, Strindberg wasn't even born until 1849, and Ibsen's first naturalistic play, Pillars of Society, wasn't performed until 1877, but it is notable that the roots of modern theater are in Scandinavia, and the pioneering of the aforementioned required a new acting style that was formalized with Stanislavsky's "method" a few decades later.  But, as with many artistic movements, the ideas for the new forms may be floating around in the collective consciousness before they are actualized.

The reason I ask is because, unlike the other deceivers on the show, who rely on the old style of acting (in particular, Durant, whose delivery of lies is distinctly declamatory,) all of the Swede's choices and mannerisms in his manipulations and deceptions seem to come from a deep, psychological place.

Actor Christopher Heyerdahl's performance is so distinct from the other actors on the show, I have to wonder if there is an intended nod to the birth of realism in theater.

Comment: Darnit, never heard of this show before... but your question makes me want to go check out 5 seasons of it, just to get to where your question starts ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin if you like Westerns, the show will hit the spot. Although the quality of the acting in general is all over the map (and in truth, tends toward the bottom of the spectrum,) Anson Mount, who plays the leading role, is excellent and Heyerdahl you just can't tear your eyes away from.

Comment: Last *good* western I ever saw was Deadwood... in fact possibly the only *good* western TV show [as opposed to movie] I've ever seen, though it petered out after a couple of seasons.

Comment: @Tetsujin Been binge-watching Deadwood per your recommendation. The writing, production values and performances in Hell on Wheels are quite up to the HBO standard, but it series has that *rollicking* feeling so many great Westerns have, and Anson Mount was born to play that role. All US school children learn about the Intercontinental Railroad and the golden spike, and the finale re: the mythic history of the West actually brought a tear to my eye.

Comment: ' ' *Won't you ring, old hammer.... Hammer ring. Won't you ring, old hammer.... Hammer ring.* ' '